# How to get sorted Entity and their attributes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data

I have the following model
[image]
[image]

I am able to sort the `Category` Entity using `NSDescriptor`, but the `children` attribute (an NSSet) is not sorted. How can I make `childrens` sorted?

Comment: What does the last part of your question mean?

Comment: I mean is it possible to get sorted not only entity but entity's attributes too. For example: I want to get Category list and when I need to `show category.childrens` `childrens` atribute will be sorted, now it's not sorted (because return format is `NSSet`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each fetched category, you would have to sort the children yourself.

```
NSArray *sortedChildren = [category.children sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
   [NSArray arrayWithObject:
      [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];
```

*BTW: The plural of "child" is "children".*